# How do I plant the arms of a fallen saguaro cactus?

Tags: cactus

I have a 32' tall Saguaro cactus in my backyard that fell down 1 week ago.  I was hoping to save and replant some of the undamaged arms that are still attached to the main trunk.  The arms range in size from less than 1' to 15' in length.  Any suggestions?

Base of saguaro where pulled out of ground:

[image]

Saguaro with several intact arms visible

[image]

(click to enlarge images)

Answer (score 1):

Some say it can't be done and others say it can.

A quote from Bruce Law who testifies that he has made it work.
From *[Propagation of the Saguaro Cactus from the Arms of the Saguaro Cactus](https://cals.arizona.edu/OALS/urbanization/saguaro.html)*

> I currently have more than 50 saguaro arms successfully rooted; many are more than 1.5 years old. During the project, I discovered that the arms required more moisture than entire cacti, therefore planting them in soil with little drainage, watering them frequently, and using rooting hormones and wood ashes was important. The University of Arizona told me that they would live for two years but would not grow roots. Contrary to this, I spoke with many individuals who have successfully grown saguaros from the arms and have kept them alive for up to 17 years.

It would be worth a try.